# Index match on first non-zero result

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, filter, match, google-sheets-formula

Trying to do an index/match lookup to find the first non-zero result among multiple matches. Not sure exactly how to do this. Sample data below.

```
Foo 1
bar 0
bar 2
```

Want to do the following:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH("Foo",A:A,0))
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH("bar",B:B,0))
```

Want the above results to return 1 and 2, but obviously based on the table above will get 1 and 0.  How can I exclude 0-values from the match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter and sortn is the way to go, but if you did want to do it by classic index/match you'd need

```
=index(B:B,match(1,(A:A="Bar")*(B:B<>0),0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=FILTER(B:B, B:B<>0)
```

if that is not enough you can do:

```
=INDEX(SORTN(FILTER(A:B, B:B<>0), 9^9, 2, 1, 0),,2)
```

if even that is still not enough try:

```
=INDEX(SORT(SORTN(FILTER({A:B, ROW(A:A)}, B:B<>0), 9^9, 2, 1, 0), 3, 1),,2)
```